# connecting to MongoDB using mongoose (node.js) while schema was already defined (in Java)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB in Node.js through Mongoose. All examples talk about first designing a schema for your documents before attempting to save and find documents.

However, I've already defined lot's of schema's in MongoDB using java (Morphia) . Is there any way I could leverage the already (implicitly) existing schema's in MongoDB in Mongoose? I.e: I can imagine meta-data being stored in MongoDB about the types of documents being created, which could be used by Mongoose to create it's own client-side schema's.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm scratch that question, Mongoose seems to be just fine with querying for fields not defined in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can imagine meta-data being stored in MongoDB about the types of documents being created, which could be used by Mongoose to create it's own client-side schema's.

MongoDB has absolutely no metadata about what's inside a collection. There's no "field-map" or common types. The indexes don't even have statistics last I checked.

> Is there any way I could leverage the already (implicitly) existing schema's in MongoDB in Mongoose?

The best I can think of would be a programmatic conversion. *i.e.: read the java source files and write out a JS version*.

Or you can simply not define the schema at all. You will still get back perfectly useful JS objects.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are correct, and here's a piece of code that worked for me:

```
mongoose.model('Cat', new mongoose.Schema({ CatId: String })); // my schema is known to have cat id (I might not need this actually)

var mondb = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'kitten'); // connect to kitten db
var c = mondb.model('Cat'); // get the cat model from mongoose connection
c.find({name:"lior"}).exec(function(err,c) { // and now use it with different fields for queries
   if (err) {
    ...
   }
   else
       ...
   }
);
```